# How to Make the ylab Visibale

Tags: r

how can I make the "Hot dogs and buns (HBD) eaten" visible?

```
hotdogs <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/hot-dog-contest-winners.csv", 
                    sep=",", header = TRUE)
                    
fill_colors <- c()
for ( i in 1:length(hotdogs$New.record) ) {
  if (hotdogs$New.record[i] == 1) {
    fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#821122")
  } else {
    fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#cccccc")
  }
}

barplot(hotdogs$Dogs.eaten, names.arg = hotdogs$Year, main = "Nathan's Hot Dog Eating Contest Results, 1980 -2010", col=fill_colors,
        border = NA, space = 0.3, xlab = "Year", ylab = "Hot dogs and buns (HBD)
        eaten")
```

After running the code, this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the ylab code is not the entire sentence. Any suggestion? Thank you so much

Comment: before running your `barplot` statement  try running `par(mar=c(5,7,4,2))`

Comment: Use vectorized `fill_colors <- ifelse(hotdogs$New.record == 1, "#821122", "#cccccc")` instead of the `for` loop.